# Ansible Inventory Not Ordering Alphabetically

Tags: ansible, hosts

I'm having the following Ansible hosts file:

```ini
# Contains the host mappings
[master]
m1.my-host.com ansible_host=192.168.0.100

[node]
n1.my-host.com ansible_host=192.168.0.102
n2.my-host.com ansible_host=192.168.0.103

[k3s_cluster:children]
master
node

[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

In my playbook, I'm saying that I need an ordered execution like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Setup hostname, users and groups
  hosts: all
  order: sorted
  gather_facts: true
  remote_user: myuser
  become: yes

  roles:
    - {role: common, tags: ['host', 'system']}
```

But when I ran it, I get to see the following:

```yaml
TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [n1.my-host.com]
ok: [n2.my-host.com]
ok: [m1.my-host.com]
```

I would have rather expected it to be m1, n1 and then n2. Is there any idea as to why the sort order is not respected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sort order *is* being respected, but because Ansible executes tasks against multiple hosts *in parallel*, you see the results in the order in which the task completes.

If you were to serialize your task execution like this:

```
- hosts: all
  order: sorted
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

You would see that the order of execution is consistently:

1. m1.my-host.com
2. n1.my-host.com
3. n2.my-host.com

Generally you don't want to serialize execution like that because it dramatically increases the runtime of your playbook, but if you have a very large number of hosts it sometimes makes sense to use a number `>` 1 to execute tasks in batches.

Comment: What is the effect of having --forks=1 instead of serial?

Comment: `serial` controls the size of a batch, while `--forks` controls the number of parallel connections. In many cases the practical effect will be the same, but when using `serial` a task must complete on all of the hosts in a batch before Ansible begins processing the next batch, while with `--forks`, a new connection can be established as soon as any existing connection is complete.

Comment: See also https://medium.com/devops-srilanka/difference-between-forks-and-serial-in-ansible-48677ebe3f36, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179199/difference-between-async-forks-serial-in-ansible, https://tekneed.com/using-ansible-serial-forks-to-contol-playbooks/, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to specify this serial on a individual task? I guess I need it only in one task while the others can run in parallel.

Comment: You may want the [`throttle`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#restricting-execution-with-throttle) keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I will give throttle a try!